# windows reboot and select proper boot device access BIOS

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, bios

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 - i7559 laptop with windows 10. I modified some BIOS boot settings. I changed UEFI boot to legacy, and modified the boot priorities. That causes my laptop to not be able to boot anymore. I am stuck in this window everytime I try to open my laptop.
[image]

I did some research and found out that I have to access to the BIOS menu on startup to modify my boot priorities back to the original ones to be able to boot again. To do so, I have to press a key such as F2 to access the BIOS menu. But after a lot of attemps I cannot access the BIOS menu. I have tried pressing continuously and holding the list of keys below right after I have pressed power button to start my laptop:

`ESC, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11, F12, DELETE, Shift, CTRL+ALT+DELETE`

None of the keys above enable me to access the BIOS menu, they all lead to the reboot and select proper device menu. How to access the BIOS menu in my case? I am sure that my keyboard works.

Comment: You have a chicken and an egg problem.  You can't properly boot due to the fact you don't have an MBR disk connected to your system.  Additionally. the last boot option being used, is PXE which is an INOP option for a home configuration.  In the future don't switch a device using a GPT disk to Legacy mode.  **Windows boots if UEFI mode is enabled when it's installed to a GPT disk.**

Comment: I will never change to legacy anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause of the issue is, "holding the list of keys below **right after I have pressed power button**."

Some PC's boot so rapidly that you must **press and hold** the <kbd>F2</kbd> key **prior** to turning on power, and **keep it held** until the BIOS interface starts.

You may also try pressing and holding <kbd>F12</kbd>, as above, to change boot device to your HDD or USB flash drive.

Another likely issue, as mentio0end by @ziggy32, is that the computer was not *fully* shut down the last time it was used. If you've enabled Hibernate or [Windows Fast Startup](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/what-is-windows-10s-fast-startup/), **files are left on the disk, and the OS looks for them at startup.** Since the files are not available, you get stuck in that loop. One way to force a clean start is to **hold the power button down for 5 or 10 seconds after letting the PC boot as far as it can go. This should force the *next* startup to be from "scratch".

If that fails, another possibility is that the [BIOS memory may need to be reset](https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Dell-Inspiron-7559-Cannot-Get-Into-Bios-After-Switching-to/m-p/7311110#M55119). To do so, open the case, find the BIOS/clock coin cell, remove it, and *wait* a few minutes before reinserting it. [See the Dell Service Manual](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/inspiron-15-7559-laptop/docs) for instructions.

Comment: Tried holding F2 or F12 before power button, the same issue persists

Comment: I had to reinstallthe BIOS clock coin cell to make it work. Thank you

Comment: Glad that worked, as much as it's a nuisance to have to open the case to access the cell.

Answer (score -1):

It is indeed F2. I work with Dells all the time. Try it from a cold power off. Occasionally press F2 as soon as you turn it on.

Comment: what do you mean by from a cold power off. Like unplug my battery while the laptop is one?

Comment: From it completely tuned off. Not in sleep mode but off. Don't murder the F2 Key but sometimes you have to let it know it has been pushed. You do not want to hold the F2 key. Tap it. F12 should bring up the boot menu.